# Android always in background service with a socket connection

Tags: android, service, background

I am designing a custom application for a specific context that will run always in the same hardware and I will have full control of the software running on it.

I need to have a permanent socket connection similar as push connection to deliver small bits of data to the device. The user might change to different applications so I need to have a background service with the socket open and prevent Android to kill it. I cannot rely in 3rd parties push solutions (even Google) since the devices will not have internet connection.

I saw many posts related to this topic but all of them suggest that is not a good idea / possible. Since the app will be running in a specific context it will not harm anybody :)

could you please suggest / guide me a bit?

Chers!

Answer (score 0):

Is it a big problem that it is occasionally killed? Can't you just check if it is running and start if not? To do that in your Activity:

```
if (!isMyServiceRunning()) {
    startService();
}

...

private boolean isMyServiceRunning() {
   ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
   for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
      if (MyService.class.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
     return true;
      }
   }
   return false;
}

private void startService() {
   Intent myService = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
   startService(myService);
}
```

Comment: thats my ultimate solution, the problem I would have is to get info from the server and not having the service running. I think I should have a control in the server to know if the the message was received and processed from the android tablet. Since the activity might not be on the foreground I guess I would have to use an AlarmManager for that.

Answer (score 0):

Although i don't recommend a socket connection to be opened even while not pushing any data .You can try keeping the socket connection open by using a Async task .
whenever socket connection closes. you can spawn a Async task .

Comment: the other side might send data to the android device at any moment this is why I must have the socket always opened :)